# cannot import mainactivity because the project in use

Tags: android

I am trying to import the file in eclipse.

```
New->import->browse(for the path)->select the project->finish.
```

I followed the same way but it's not working. I received the error

```
Cannot import MainActivity because the project name is in use
```

Comment: I think project with same name might already exist in your workspace

Comment: could u please explain me in detail.

Comment: means already another project is present with same name in eclipse workspace

Comment: Sure. I am explaining you my situation. I had to work on a project called XYZ. What I did was just kept it as a backup with date as postfix. So it was XYZ10102112. On next day I imported it as XYZ11102012. Sometimes, it gave me problem. That might be a case or that might not be a case in your problem

Comment: When I had that problem i tried to import after copying the project into the workspace. When importing from somewhere outside the workspace and using the "copy to workspace" function it worked flawless.

Comment: Not sure why this question has been closed as off topic? Sound pretty related to Android programming to me. Anyway, I had the same problem. It was fixed by choosing "General, Existing Projects into Workspace" and NOT choosing "Android, Existing Android Code Into Workspace" in first step of import wizard.

Comment: Use `File->Import` rather then `File->New->Android Project from Existing Code`

Comment: @vinya  I had this problem when I defined multiple Working Sets in Eclipse.  The problem was resolved when I switched to Window Working Set (the main working set), and deleted the unused project.  Then I was able to import my new project.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the project or change the path (your place to save it on your computer) because you have the same project name in your workspace .